# How I can get status of system service in Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

How I can get the status of a system service (ie. apache)? How I can start/stop it?
I looked into "Mono.Unix.Native" namespace but could not find a method that can do the job.

Comment: I am trying to do the same, I need to know the time a particular service started at.